# pgfplotstable: How to handle correctly with pgfplotsinvokeforeach at pgfplotstablecreatecol

Tags: pgfplotstable, foreach

I get only the last value (that is '0') expanded in the following pgfplotsinvokeforeach-loop.

What have I to do?

*BTW: I would like to keep `create col/set list`. I hope it is possible.*

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablenew[
create on use/Names/.style={create col/set list={
$k$,$k^2$,$k^3$}},
columns={Names}
]{7}\modulotable

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{3,2,1,0}{%
% Calculations ================
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ksquare}{\k*\k}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kcube}{\k*\k*\k}
% Column ===================
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/set list={\k,\ksquare,\kcube}
]{\k}\modulotable
}%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\modulotable

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablenew[
create on use/Names/.style={create col/set list={
$k$,$k^2$,$k^3$}},
columns={Names}
]{7}\modulotable

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{3,2,1,0}{%
% Calculations ================
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ksquare}{\k*\k}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kcube}{\k*\k*\k}
% Column ===================
\edef\next{%
\noexpand\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/set list={\k,\ksquare,\kcube}
  ]{\k}\noexpand\modulotable}\next
}%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\modulotable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good, Mrs. Fischer! This helps me a lot at my great project.